How to catch error and continue after a mysql error
I have the following code:
$squery = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%configuration_lang'";
$sres = dbquery($squery);
while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($sres)) {
  $vquery = 'SELECT value FROM `' . $srow["TABLE_SCHEMA"] . '`.' . $prefix . 'configuration WHERE name="PS_VERSION_DB"';
  try {
    $vres = @mysqli_query($conn, $vquery);
  } catch (Throwable $t) {
    continue;
  }
  $vrow = mysqli_fetch_array($vres);
  ...further processing
}

Some tables are defect and throw a 1932 error ("table doesn't exist") in the inner query. I try to ignore this with the catch structure.
However, what happens is that I will just get the same error with the next query ($srow=mysqli_fetch_array($sres)).
Why does this happen? And is there anything that I can do about it?

Why not check why this is happening in the first place? Having defect tables sounds like something you should fix first

You can just remove the code that tries to access the non-existent tables. If it's never going to work then what's the point in keeping it.

Instead of using mysqli_fetch_array you could use mysqli_fetch_all in the try block but I doubt it's going to help much.

"However, what happens is that I will just get the same error with the next query ("$srow=mysqli_fetch_array($sres")." What does this mean?

@Dharman could it be that recent bug you were fixing, when the error didn't clear between queries?

@YourCommonSense It must have been quite a while ago because I can't remember the details anymore. OP didn't specify their PHP version

@YourCommonSense Do you mean this one https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a59868aef8e00ae4eadb752e28166237769e2541

If OP can specify the PHP version then I can reopen and answer it.

@Dharman It looks indeed like this Github bug. It was PHP 8.1.

This was a PHP bug which got fixed in PHP 8.2.20. It has existed since PHP 7.4.26. You just need to upgrade your PHP installation to the latest version or at least one of the supported ones.
